# addClass() is not adding the class

Tags: jquery, html, addclass

I am using jQuery for the first time to add a class to an element within the navigation bar, but the class, '.selected' isn't being added.

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/v32qy/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` is not a jQuery object, it's the actual DOM element. To turn it into a jQuery object, use `$(this)`. So:

```
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

Another problem in the jsFiddle is that you're not selecting the `<a>` element, you're selecting the `<h2>`. Finally, the link is being followed. [Here's all that fixed.](http://jsfiddle.net/v32qy/3/)

---

<sup>Something else you might consider is that `element.innerText` doesn't have very good browser support from what I've seen (i.e. it only works in IE). Just a small point of note.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but the font colour isn't actually changing, could you tell me why?

Comment: @max_: This time it's a CSS issue - one of *specificity*. Your CSS rules for the links are much more specific, so they override the not-so-specific rule `.selected`. You can fix it by [adding !important](http://jsfiddle.net/v32qy/7/). This doesn't work in IE6, though, so either make `.selected` more specific or make your other rules less specific.

Answer (score 0):

You want apply the class to the anchor, in addition to correcting the syntax.

```
$('#textContainer h2 a').click(function() {
    var title = this.innerText;
    $(this).addClass('selected');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the current element you have to use `$(this)` and not just `this`

Here is the updated fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/v32qy/6/

I have also changed the way you are getting the inner text to use jQuery `text()` function